# Date columns not in right format when exporting from DBeaver to csv

Tags: excel, dbeaver

When I export my results from dbeaver to a csv file my timestamps would show incorrectly when open in Excel and I would have to format the column every time. For example `2023-07-20 17:27:30.000` would be shown as `27:30.0` when first opened. Is there a way to solve this so I don't need to format the column in Excel every time?

Not really sure what methods to try and fix this.

Comment: You probably need to **import** and not **open** the  file